# How to derive one equation including only one variable from five equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The variables: H, M, X,Y,Z

The five equations:
$$ 
7.6\times{10^{-3}} =\frac{X H}{M} \tag{1}$$
$$6.2\times{10^{-8}} =\frac{Y H}{X} \tag{2}$$
$$2.1\times{10^{-13}} =\frac{Z H}{Y} \tag{3}$$
$$H^2 +0.3H = X H + 2Y H + 3ZH+10^{-14}\tag{4} $$
$$0.3 = M +  X  +  Y +  Z\tag{5} $$
**Quistion** : Derive equation containing just **H** variable.

Comment: Eliminate $M,X,Y,Z$ successively (naively) gives a degree 16 equation.  This doesn't look like `precalculus`.

Comment: @user10354138Can the degree 16 equation be solved by computer? How?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a chemical problem. When I saw it, I suspected possible traps because of the very small numbers and I rewrote the equations as
$$a =\frac{X H}{M} \tag{1}$$
$$b =\frac{Y H}{X} \tag{2}$$
$$c =\frac{Z H}{Y} \tag{3}$$
$$H^2 +\frac 3 {10}H = X H + 2Y H + 3ZH+d\tag{4} $$
$$\frac 3 {10}= M +  X  +  Y +  Z\tag{5} $$

In a first step, as  @user10354138 commented, I used equations $(1,2,3,5)$ to express $X,Y,Z,M$ as functions of $H$. This leads to
$$X=\frac{3 a H^2}{10 \left(a b c+a b H+a H^2+H^3\right)}\qquad \qquad Y=\frac{3 a b H}{10 \left(a b c+a b H+a H^2+H^3\right)}$$
$$Z=\frac{3 a b c}{10 \left(a b c+a b H+a H^2+H^3\right)}\qquad \qquad M=\frac{3 H^3}{10 \left(a b c+a b H+a H^2+H^3\right)}$$
Now, replace these expressions in $(4)$, reduce to same denominator (which we shall ignore assuming it is non-zero) and put everything on the same side. We shall get
$$-10 a b c d-2  a b (3 c+5 d)H+a  (b (10 c-3)-10 d)H^2+10  (a b-d)H^3+(10 a+3)
   H^4+10 H^5=0\tag 6$$  This is just a polynomial of degree $5$ which cannot be solved analytically and for which numerical methods will be required.

Replace $a,b,c,d$ by their values; you will get very ugly values for the coefficients.

If you want to solve $(6)$ for $H$, since we know the usual ranges of $H$, use inspection with $H=10^{-pH}$. Plotting the function as a function of $pH$, you will notice a very fast decreasing function with a solution close to $pH=4$. So, start Newton iterations  using $pH_0=4$. You should get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & pH_n \\
 0 & 4.00000 \\
 1 & 4.10601 \\
 2 & 4.21036 \\
 3 & 4.31193 \\
 4 & 4.40889 \\
 5 & 4.49815 \\
 6 & 4.57469 \\
 7 & 4.63121 \\
 8 & 4.66103 \\
 9 & 4.66846 \\
 10 & 4.66886
\end{array}
\right)$$ that is to say $H=10^{-4.66886}=0.0000214358$.

**Edit**

Plotting the function given by $(6)$ is not very good. You can have a much better perception using $H=10^{-pH}$ and plot, as a function of $pH$
$$f(pH)=\frac{H^2 +\frac 3 {10}H } {X H + 2Y H + 3ZH+d }-1\tag 7$$ and look for its zero. Zoom once around the solution to get an estimate of $4.7$.

Solving $(7)$, using as before $pH_0=4$, Newton iterations would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & pH_n \\
 0 & 4.00000 \\
 1 & 4.39558 \\
 2 & 4.63729 \\
 3 & 4.66879 \\
 4 & 4.66886
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is much faster than the previous one.

Comment: I appreciate your interest and your effort in helping for solving the math part of the chemical problem posted in Chem.Stack Exchange **how do I calculate the concentration of all species present in a solution with$\pu{ 0.3M}\ce{ NaH2PO4}$: So the concentration of$\ce{ H3PO4, H2PO4 -, HPO4 2-, PO4 3- }$  and $\ce{H3O+}$.**.

Comment: @AdnanAL-Amleh. Why don't you write all the balance equations first and post them in a question here (on MSE) ? Tell me when done and I shall have a look at the problem.

Comment: Leibovicithanks a lot, I will post the chemical problem on (MSE), and tell you when done. Now I try to  understand the  derivations  $ X,Y,Z,M$ as functions of $H$

Comment: @AdnanAL-Amleh. Just successive eliminations : from $(1)$, get $X$; replace in $(2)$ and get $Y$; replace in $(3)$ and get $Z$. Now, use $(5)$ to get $M$ and you are done.